# manually trigger jquery keyup?

Tags: jquery

**I think I figured it out... see my comment.  Sorry.**

I have a JSON web service that is called on a certain keyup() event which retrieves some data based on the input.  I would like to load an initial set of data before anything is typed.  I'm trying to manually invoke the keyup() as stated in the documentation, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
$('#inputItemName').keyup(function () {
//perform query, display results
});
```

^^ works great when you type in the box

```
$('#inputItemName').keyup();
```

^^ called immediately after document ready function, doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I think I figured it out... I moved the function that calls the results higher up in the script tag than the keyup() invocation and now it works.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes: you have to attach a function to the trigger **before** triggering it! (otherwise the event is fired, but no function is called)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/radu/gD5WL/

```
$('#test').keyup(function () {
    console.log('hello');
});

$('#test').keyup();
```

The `keyup` event is getting called on page load.

Comment: So the trick was order.  Since my answer wasn't popular, I changed the accepted answer to yours.

Comment: how about the keyCode?

Answer (score 38):

```
$('#inputItemName').trigger('keyup');
```

Answer (score 7):

Try trigger function.

`$('#inputItemName').trigger('keyup');`

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `#` in selector...
try with hash...

`$('#inputItemName').keyup();`

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out... I moved the function that calls the results higher up in the script tag than the `keyup()` invocation and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the hash marker for the id in the second one:

`$('#inputItemName').keyup();`

Comment: Sorry, just updated... I do have that in there now and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Create a jsFiddle and we'll take a look.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
$('#inputItemName').bind('keyup',function() {
    //stuff
});
```