# After ajax success update input field and fire KeyUp event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an input field being dynamically updated from an AJAX function. How do I also fire a "keyup" even so the updated input value is picked up from another JS script. Basically I'm trying to mimic a user typing a number into the input field. Thanks in advance

Here is the code I have to update the input field

```
    var interval = 500;  // 1000 = 1 second, 3000 = 3 seconds
            function doAjax() {
                $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'speed.php',
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#kilometers').val(data);


                       },
                        complete: function (data) {
                                // Schedule the next
                                setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
                        }
               });
            }
            setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
            $('#kilometers').keyup(update);``
```

Comment: What does `update` function do?

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/a/6511891/1992669 ?