# Can Javascript simulate "keyup" programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sale page with a coupon text field.
For my influencers campaign, I create a new coupon for each new influencer.

As I want to make their life easy, I code some javascript to prefill the "coupon" textfield of the sale page with their promocode from url parameter
mysite.com/mysalepage?coupon=NAME_OF_INFLUENCER

But people can also arrive in this sale landing page without the influencer and type themself their coupon code they found somewhere in our social pages.
[image: coupon field]

And when a visitor type their coupon code in the textfield, it hides the price and payment button AND shows the new price and the new payment button.

[image: promo code typed by hand]

These show/hide function is trigger by "Keyup" and it works fine when visitor type the promo code.

**Unfortunately, it doesn't work when it is my javascript code which fill the coupon textfield from my url parameter.**

So I tried to create by code some different events on my page and trigger it in order to show/hide the promotion elements. I tried "scroll, focusin, focusout,etc"...

The code focus on element when I asked to do it, but it doesn't get triggered by my code which show/hide the promotion elements.

Here is my code:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript"
language = "Javascript" >
  // Function to hide/show the table based on the values of inputs
  function toggleTable() {


    $('#hideThis').toggle($('#coupon').val() !== 'JDCM' && $('#coupon').val() !== 'PROMOGH2019');
    $('#hideThis3').toggle($('#coupon').val() !== 'JDCM' && $('#coupon').val() !== 'PROMOGH2019');
    $('#showThis').toggle($('#coupon').val() == 'JDCM' || $('#coupon').val() == 'PROMOGH2019');
    $('#showThis2').toggle($('#coupon').val() == 'JDCM' || $('#coupon').val() == 'PROMOGH2019');
    $('#showThis3').toggle($('#coupon').val() == 'JDCM' || $('#coupon').val() == 'PROMOGH2019');
  }

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Bind the keyup event on both the inputs, call the function on event
  $('#coupon').on('keyup', toggleTable).trigger('keyup');
  $('#begin').on('scroll', toggleTable).trigger('scroll');
});


window.onload = function() {

  function querySt(ji) {

    hu = window.location.search.substring(1);
    gy = hu.split("&");

    for (i = 0; i < gy.length; i++) {
      ft = gy[i].split("=");
      if (ft[0] == ji) {
        return ft[1];
      }
    }
  }
  var coupon = querySt("coupon");


  if (coupon == null) {} else {
    document.getElementById('coupon').value = coupon;
  }
}

document.getElementById('coupon').focus();

document.getElementById('begin').focus(); <
/script>
```

```html
<form>
  <span>Vous avez un code PROMO?</span><input type="text" name="coupon" id="coupon" placeholder="Ex: PROMO2019">
</form>

<div id="showThis">
  <div>
    <b style="color:#000000;">Prix HT:<strike>594€</strike></b>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="hideThis">
  <div>
    <b>Prix HT:594€</b>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="showThis2">
  <div>
    <b>Remise  exceptionnelle de -50%</b>
    <br><br>
    <b style="color:#36C503;">Prix final à payer: 297€</b>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="hideThis3">
  <div class="div_button">
    <a href="URL_594_euros" class="myButton"><span>&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;Acheter Maintenant 594€</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="showThis3">
  <div class="div_button">
    <a href="URL_297_euros" class="myButton"><span>&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;Acheter Maintenant 297€</a>
  </div>
  <div>
```

On the code, you can see I tried to show/hide on scroll event, but it didn't work.

I was wondering how to create by code this event "keyup" on my textfield coupon.

Comment: Why not just use `trigger('keyup')` like you already do in your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [manually trigger jquery keyup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511846/manually-trigger-jquery-keyup)

Comment: On key up, you run the `toggleTable()` function, right? So, instead of emulating / triggering a keyup event in order to consequently run this function, why don't you simply run the `toggleTable()` function directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after the code that fills the coupon just trigger the `keyup` event manually:

```
$('#coupon').keyup();
```